# Cant connect to TOR network

Tags: connection

i wanted to start using TOR, but sadly i am not able to connect.
These are the error messages:

```
9/18/21, 19:18:58.603 [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections. 
9/18/21, 19:18:58.603 [NOTICE] Opening Socks listener on 127.0.0.1:9150 
9/18/21, 19:19:00.681 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 5%: Connecting to directory server 
9/18/21, 19:19:00.682 [NOTICE] Bootstrapped 10%: Finishing handshake with directory server 
9/18/21, 19:19:21.738 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 131.252.210.150:8080 ("TTL expired") 
9/18/21, 19:19:21.739 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 128.105.214.163:8080 ("TTL expired") 
9/18/21, 19:19:21.739 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 128.105.214.161:8080 ("TTL expired") 
9/18/21, 19:19:21.739 [WARN] Proxy Client: unable to connect to 128.105.214.162:8080 ("TTL expired")
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems like you are failing to connect to a SOCKS proxy. If a SOCKS proxy is required for your network setup, then please make sure you’ve entered your proxy details correctly. If a SOCKS proxy is not required, or you’re not sure, please try connecting to the Tor network without a SOCKS proxy.

Comment: How am i able to find this out? I am using a internet provider who only provides ipv6 adresses if this helps.

Comment: Have you configured your Tor Browser or the network settings of your operating system  in any way?

Comment: Just saw your update; re: I am using a internet provider who only provides ipv6 adresses if this helps. 
I don't think that should be a problem.

Answer (score 0):

Somehow, DisableNetwork is enabled according your log.

> [NOTICE] DisableNetwork is set. Tor will not make or accept non-control network connections. Shutting down all existing connections.

So you cannot connect if your directory information is insufficient to connect to the network.

Edit your torrc to enable connections.

Are you using tails?

> In the Welcome Screen the "Network Configuration" section contains a non-default option called "My Internet Connection is censored...". When activated, the following deviations from normal Tails behaviour occur, in order:
> Tails sessions begin with DisableNetwork 1 in torrc so Tor will not connect to the network without user intervention.

According to [tails doc](https://tails.boum.org/contribute/design/Tor_network_configuration/)

Answer (score 0):

If it's a Tor browser's *tor* process - use a separate one, a lot of tools like Tor Browser has caused it by ridiculously issuing this command to the node. There's no practical use for this even on a mobile networks: you can save 90% of traffic easily using a different tactics but without disabling the network. If you disable network - then you will need to re-integrate in it when you resume, and saving like 2-5 megabytes of traffic here sounds like a bad idea, IMHO